# Android app crashes when accessing most of the posts

Tags: bug, android-app

If I try to access a Q&A thread, the app crashes. It happens on many questions of every site of Stack Exchange.

After doing thorough research, I found that it happens like 95% of the time. Most questions of Stack Overflow can be opened, but other sites mostly give crashes if any answer is opened.

Update: It started happening even on this post after I got 3 comments on this one. It seems if a Q&A thread has more than 2 comments, the app crashes...

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-F160K

  - OS Version: 4.1.2 (F160K20j.1403336137)

Comment: Can you please clarify what site you're on that this is occurring? Is it all questions on all sites?

Comment: No Catija. Not every question. Clarified in the question.

Comment: Have you tried force quitting the app/restarting your phone?

Comment: Yes Catija it doesn't work, and sorry for late reply I went to sleep last night.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the app, and install again from the Play Store?

Comment: Yes Shadow Wizard. It didn't work...

Comment: Were you browsing SE on browser at the same time? Did you dismiss any notification from the web?

Comment: Not browsing at the same time. And about dismissal, I've just seen the notifications on web as the mobile app isn't working.